# Weblogic 12c clustered timer issues

Tags: timer, weblogic, ejb-3.1, weblogic12c

Has anybody been able to run timers in clustered WebLogic 12c (version 12.1.2-patched)?

We keep getting errors and are not confident that it could work in 12.1.2. Does anybody have it working in clustered 12.1.3?

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem? What errors? We're running clustered weblogic with timers and haven't had any issues

Comment: @castling: Are those timers clustered? Meaning they only run on one node of the cluster at any time?

Answer (score 0):

the project with the clustered timer also used CDI and had an empty beans.xml. Looks like CDI forces some other kind of proxying of the timer bean not compatible with the timer implementation. After removing the beans.xml and so disabling CDI the timer works.